# What do Americans call a "lie-in"?

Tags: phrases, idioms, dialects

The Random House dictionary [gives](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/lie-in) the main definition of "lie-in" as:

> a protest demonstration in which participants lie down in a public place against regulations and resist being moved.

The definition I'm more familiar with, given second, is:

> an act or instance of staying in bed longer than usual, especially in the morning.

This is marked as "chiefly British".  So what's the American equivalent?  Or do Americans still use "lie-in"... would they understand the "bed" meaning of the term?

Comment: Yeah, I don't recall commonly encountering "lie-in" until it began being used fairly recently to describe a demonstration.

Comment: Americans might call it a "sit-in" (a demonstration, not "sleeping in".

Answer (score 2):

Within my (American) experience, "have a lie-in" is not used in the US. Instead, one would use "sleep late".

Comment: Even if you're not actually sleeping but have simply decided not to get up?

Comment: I would say "sleep in".  Might even be used when you get up but stay in your jammies for a fairly long period.

Comment: @AndrewLeach - Especially if you're just going to not get up.

Answer (score 0):

For the "staying in bed later than usual" meaning (not the protest meaning): definitely "sleeping in."